# Trash in my python file

Tags: python, utf-8, ansi

I am making a script in Python to take some scripts and put them in a determined size (37 in this case), adding some white spaces if necessary. I finished it and I thought it worked pretty well but then I saw that changing the encodings from Ansi to Utf-8 and viceversa the spaces has some trash. Here it is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import sys
import openpyxl
import codecs

doc_name = input('Enter Excel document name: ')
wb = load_workbook(doc_name + '.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
sql = open(doc_name + '.sql','w')
column = input('Enter column where I can find gescal (usually B): ')
i = 1
while True:
    '''If cell empty finish'''
    cell = ws[column + str(i)].value
    if cell == None:
        break
    '''Calculate Gescal 37'''
    lengthcell = len(cell)
    if lengthcell < 37:
        gescal37 = cell + (' '*(37-lengthcell))
    elif lengthcell > 37:
        gescal37 = cell[:37]
    else:
        gescal37 = cell
    '''Calculate gescal 17'''
    gescal17 = gescal37[:17]
    '''Write it in the document'''
    sql.write('update installationuser set GESCAL37 = \'' + gescal37 + '\' where GESCAL37 = \'' + gescal17 + '\';\n')
    i += 1
sql.close()
```

I tried to open the document with the utf-8 encoding, but I had the same problem in the other way. It looks pretty good with encoding utf-8 but when I tried to show it with the Ansi encoding... bang! the white spaces had trash.

Comment: UTF-8 contains multiple invisible characters. ANSI does not. Can you share the strings that were causing issues?

Comment: the strings are this form: "aaaaaaaaaaaa                 aa              " and I am having troubles only in the whitespaces. If I use utf-8 in my script and then I read using utf-8 everything is ok, if I use Ansi to read I obtain this "Â " instead of a whitespace. In the other hand, if I use Ansi in my script and then I read using Ansi everything ok, if I use utf-8 I obtain "xA0" instead of a whitespace. Finally, if I intruduce whitespaces manually I have no problem reading with Ansi or utf-8. @Krets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\xa0` is a non-breaking space.
Try to use `gescal = gescal.replace(u'\xa0', ' ')` to replace it with a space.